# fast-r-cnn: caffe.LayerParameter" has no field named "roi_pooling_param

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

When I tried to run ./tools/demo.py of [fast-r-cnn](https://github.com/rbgirshick/fast-rcnn). working on UBUNTU 16.04
I got the following error, although the caffe is successfully installed!!

> ./tools/demo.py

```
WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
W0823 14:12:46.105280  4444 _caffe.cpp:122] DEPRECATION WARNING - deprecated use of Python interface
W0823 14:12:46.105316  4444 _caffe.cpp:123] Use this instead (with the named "weights" parameter):
W0823 14:12:46.105319  4444 _caffe.cpp:125] Net('/home/hana/Documents/try/fast-rcnn-master/models/VGG16/test.prototxt', 1, weights='/home/hana/Documents/try/fast-rcnn-master/data/fast_rcnn_models/vgg16_fast_rcnn_iter_40000.caffemodel')
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/text_format.cc:274] Error parsing text-format caffe.NetParameter: 392:21: Message type "caffe.LayerParameter" has no field named "roi_pooling_param".
F0823 14:12:46.106595  4444 upgrade_proto.cpp:79] Check failed: ReadProtoFromTextFile(param_file, param) Failed to parse NetParameter file: /home/hana/Documents/try/fast-rcnn-master/models/VGG16/test.prototxt
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Please any help?

Comment: are you sure you are running the correct caffe version? fast-r-cnn has a special branch of caffe with some modifications.

Comment: Thanks!
Exactly this was my problem :|

Answer (score 3):

Faster-RCNN [requires its own branch of caffe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39099783/fast-r-cnn-caffe-layerparameter-has-no-field-named-roi-pooling-param/42484929#comment65623316_39099783). This branch includes `roi_pooling_layer` and its associated parameters.

Follow the [installation instructions of Faster RCNN](https://github.com/rbgirshick/fast-rcnn#installation-sufficient-for-the-demo) to get the correct branch of caffe.